# How to set context menu on touchpad top right button?

Tags: windows, touchpad, thinkpad, mouse-click

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W510 and I want to change touchpad top right button behavior and set Windows Context Menu or Mouse Right Click.

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new settings interface of the Synaptics driver, there is no option to enable this feature. However, is still possible enable this from the system registry:

- Open Registry Editor (Windows + R, type **regedit** and hit Enter)
  Navigate to
- *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2TM28xx*
- Change the value of **2FingerTapAction** to 2

[Source](https://www.andreafortuna.org/technology/windows-10-enable-right-click-with-two-fingers-tap-on-synaptics-touchpad/)